# Spring Security Oauth2 em API Rest

Tags: java, restful, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth2

Bom dia.

Eu tenho um Web Service Rest implementado e estou trabalhando na segurança do mesmo no momento.

Este Web Service foi implementado usando o Spring Boot. Inicialmente vou ter como clientes um Aplicativo para Android e um Aplicativo web, mas no futuro eu penso em tornar essa API pública, então eu tenho que pensar sobre esse isso também.

Eu pesquisei muito sobre Spring Security Oauth2, mas tenho basicamente duas dúvidas:

- Todos os exemplos que eu vi até agora têm sido usando um cliente Web App, onde o servidor redireciona para as url's de autenticação. Em uma aplicação Android, como é feita esta autenticação? Afinal, eu não estou trabalhando com Html no Android para ser redirecionado.
- Preciso do login no Facebook, onde o usuário poderá compartilhar a partir da App. Inicialmente eu pensei sobre a possibilidade de os app's clientes serem responsáveis por realizar essa autenticação e de alguma forma enviá-la para o meu servidor posteriormente, pois creio que seria mais prático do que Spring Social. Isso é possível?

Muito Obrigado, e todas as dicas sobre a arquitetura de meu caso de uso serão bem-vindas.

Comment: Interessante a tua pergunta. No caso do aplicativo Android, eu faria a autenticação sem o redirecionamento, mas sim chamando um serviço que me devolvesse o ticket de autenticação e aí esperando a resposta para seguir o fluxo adequado no aplicativo. E a segunda pergunta é exatamente isso que eu faria também. Implementaria tudo do lado do servidor. Quando é aplicativo em dispositivo móvel, é sempre bom deixar os processamentos no lado do servidor, até porque não existem muitos recursos nativos para fazer muita coisa.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo comentário!!! Concordo com seu raciocínio, mas queria algum framework que me apoiasse nisso, pois se tratando de segurança existem N preocupações que um framework resolveria. Conhece algo nesse sentido?